# Remove Support for outlook 2013 in Outlook add in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-store

Outlook add in was rejected because it was not working in outlook 2013. How to remove support for outlook 2013 from outlook add in manifest file ??

We also tried testing for outlook 2013 but we get its no more supported from microsoft to download

Outlook 2013 for mac cannot be downloaded

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-2013-and-office-for-mac-2011-are-no-longer-available-for-installation-with-an-office-365-subscription-de68fd95-553a-4c38-b1b5-e4205b96fc75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Outlook add-ins declare what API versions they require by using the
>   Requirements element in their manifest. Outlook add-ins always include
>   a Set element with a Name attribute set to Mailbox and a MinVersion
>   attribute set to the minimum API requirement set that supports the
>   add-in's scenarios.

for your case

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Read more at [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets)

Comment: Setting MinVersion="1.5" will remove support for Outlook 2016 also. Is there any way to remove support for outlook 2013 only ??